# Freemarker macro with boolean variable

Tags: macros, freemarker, boolean-expression

I am using Freemarker 2.3.28 in Spring and Freemarker application.
I have a trouble getting booleans working with freemarker macros.

I getting a JSON from server-side which has one attribute as boolean (verified with JS typeof function).
I am putting this data in a template using:

```
<script id="data-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   <@customData var1="{{var_id}}" var2="{{var_label}}" var3="{{var_enabled}}" />
</script>
```

var3 in this expression is coming as boolean, which I want to use for some checkbox expression to make it checked or unchecked.

Now when I use this as macro-expression as follows, it is not picking the var3 as boolean:

```
<#macro customData var1 var2 var3>   
   <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" ${var3?string('checked="true"', ''} />Dummy Label</label>
   </div>
</#macro>
```

I get the error when I use ?string:

```
FreeMarker template error:
For "...(...)" callee: Expected a method, but this has evaluated to a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar):
==> var3?string
```

If I use ?then it gives error:

```
FreeMarker template error:
For "?then(...)" left-hand operand: Expected a boolean, but this has evaluated to a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar):
==> var3
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose FreeMarker is evaluted before the `{{...}}` parts, so the FreeMarker macro literally gets `"{{var_id}}"`, which is a string literal. So the basic approach of the problem seems to be incorrect.

Also, even if Handlebars is evaluated first, you end up with things like `var3="true"`, which is again a string literal in FreeMarker, because of the quotation marks around it.